# How to get detail data from the FlatList react-native using react-navigation with the trigger is button onPress() from native base?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have using this API for a week and manipulate the data:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=9a4a662a126525b07d4b84b079d809d8&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.asc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1

Each data have a id, example if you inspect that JSON file, example the title movie like "How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World" and that movie have id is 166428, from my Flatlist to show all the data movies become list, and is it worked, just like general movies list in mobile app, but I do not know how to get detail data and manipulate it, if I touch for detail button I got the error, navigate or whatever there is. How can I solve this?

Here the code :

MovieList.js

```
// create constructor
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // default statement
        this.state = {
            loading : false,
            data : [],
            // depends on API
            // using API TmDB API
            api_version : 3,
            api_key : '9a4a662a126525b07d4b84b079d809d8',
            language : 'en-US',
            // optional param
            sort_by : 'popularity.desc',
            include_adult_movie : false,
            include_video : false,
            page : 1,
            //
            error : null,
            refreshing : false
        };

    }

    // call the API function
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
    }
    // call the api url and manipulate it
    makeRemoteRequest = () => {
        const {
            api_version,
            api_key,
            language,
            sort_by,
            include_adult_movie,
            include_video,
            page
        } = this.state
        const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/${api_version}/discover/movie?api_key=${api_key}&language=${language}&sort_by=${sort_by}&include_adult=${include_adult_movie}&include_video=${include_video}&page=${page}`;
        this.setState({ loading : true })
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data: [...this.state.data, ...response.results],
                error: response.error || null,
                loading: false,
                // refreshing: false
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ error, loading: false});
        });
    }

    // infinite scroll
    handleLoadMore = () => {
        this.setState({
            page: this.state.page + 1,
            loading: true
        }, () => {
            this.makeRemoteRequest();
        });
    }

    // render forward to detail item
    // handleItemTouch = ({ item }) => {
    //  this.setState({
    //      movie_id: this.state.movie_id + item.id,
    //      loading: true
    //  }, () => {
    //      this.props.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", movie_id);
    //  });
    // }

    // render movie item
    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            // touchable item
                <ListItem 
                    Thumbnail
                    // onPress={() => this.handleItemTouch}
                    onPress={() => this.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", item.id)}
                >
                        <Left>
                            <Thumbnail style = {{ height: 120, borderRadius: 30/2}} square large source= {{ uri:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + item.poster_path }}/>
                                <Body>
                                    <Text style = { stylesWindow.fontMainColor } >{ item.title }</Text>
                                    <Text style = { stylesWindow.fontMainColor } note >Release Date : { item.release_date }</Text>
                                    <Text style = { stylesWindow.fontMainColor } note >Vote Avarage : { item.vote_average }</Text>
                                    <Text style = { stylesWindow.fontMainColor } note >Language : { item.original_language}</Text>
                                </Body>
                        </Left>
                            <Icon name="arrow-forward" style={ stylesWindow.iconColor }/>
                </ListItem>
        );
    }
```

MovieDetail.js

```
 // create constructor
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // default statement
        this.state = {
            loading : false,
            data : [],
            // depends on API
            // using API TmDB API
            api_version : 3,
            api_key : '9a4a662a126525b07d4b84b079d809d8',
            language : 'en-US',
            // optional param
            movie_id : null,
            //
            error : null,
            refreshing : false
        };
    }

    // call the API function
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
    }
    // call the api url and manipulate it
    makeRemoteRequest = () => {
        const {
            api_version,
            api_key,
            movie_id,
            language
        } = this.state
        const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/${api_version}/movie/${movie_id}?api_key=${api_key}&language=${language}`;
        this.setState({ loading : true })
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data: [...this.state.data, ...response.results],
                error: response.error || null,
                loading: false,
                // refreshing: false
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ error, loading: false});
        });
    }

    handleDetailData = ({ item }) => {
        this.setState({
            movie_id: this.state.movie_id + item.id,
            loading: true
        }, () => {
            this.makeRemoteRequest();
        });
    }

    // render movie item
    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            // touchable item
            <Text>{ item.title }</Text>
        );
    }


    render(){
        // const item = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        return(
            <Container>
                <Header
                    style = { stylesWindow.headerBackgroundColor }
                    androidStatusBarColor="#504F6D"
                    iosBarStyle="light-content"
                >
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name="menu" style={ stylesWindow.iconColor }/>
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                        <Body>
                            {/* <Title>{ item.title }</Title>
                            <Subtitle>{ item.release_date }</Subtitle> */}
                        </Body>
                    <Right />
                </Header>
                    <Content style = {stylesWindow.ContentStyleColor}>
                        <FlatList 
                            data = { this.state.data }
                            // render per item
                            renderItem = { this.renderItem }
                            // key list
                            keyExtractor={ this.handleDetailData }
                        />
                    </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

After I'm see your codes guys and ask in different place, my code like this

MovieList.js

```
    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            // touchable item
                <ListItem 
                    Thumbnail
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", {id: item.id})}
```

and the MovieDetail.js

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // default statement
        this.state = {
            loading : false,
            data : [],
            // depends on API
            // using API TmDB API
            api_version : 3,
            api_key : '9a4a662a126525b07d4b84b079d809d8',
            language : 'en-US',
            // optional param
            movie_id : null,
            //
            error : null,
            refreshing : false
        };
    }

    // // call the API function
    // componentDidMount = () => {
    //  this.makeRemoteRequest();
    // }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const item = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        // console.log(item);
        this.setState({
            movie_id : item.id
        }, () => {
            this.makeRemoteRequest();
        })
    }
```

and then manipulate to the render()

```
  <Content style = {stylesWindow.ContentStyleColor}>
                        <Text style = { stylesWindow.fontMainColor } >{ item.title }</Text>
                    </Content>
```

Surely show error again can't find variable item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the whole `item` in this way

```js
onPress={() => this.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", {item})}
```

then on `MovieDetail`

```js
const {item} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
// then try to read the whole item, for example
console.log(item, item.title);
```

Comment: the detail data has been show and really works! but I got this warning message "status_code":34,"status_message":"The resource you requested could not be found.

Comment: I'm trying like this : `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", {id: item.id})}`

Comment: then I call state params like this : `componentDidMount = () => {
        const item = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        // console.log(item);
        this.setState({
            movie_id : item.id
        }, () => {
            this.makeRemoteRequest();
        })
    }` the data has been show in the warn message how I get the manipulate in `render()` I'm was try call `item.title` but get the error.

Comment: You dint follow my recommendation :(  Try to do `onPress={() => this.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", {item})}` and then `componentDidMount = () => { const {item} = this.props.navigation.state.params; // console.log(item);}` Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass the whole item, so that you can call the other items like title, release_date etc. Passing `{id:item.id}` will only pass `id` itself.

> MovieList.js

```
<ListItemThumbnail
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", {item: item})}>

        .....

</ListItemThumbnail>
```

> MovieDetail.js

```
<Content style = {stylesWindow.ContentStyleColor}>
     <FlatList 
       data = {this.props.navigation.state.params.item}
       renderItem ={({item}) => 
           <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          }
      />
   </Content>
```

Comment: yes I did and using this code pattern:

MovieList.js

<ListItem 
     Thumbnail
     // onPress={() => this.handleItemTouch}
     onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MovieListData_Detail", {id: item.id})}
    >


  in MovieDetail.js

I'm using this code  const item = this.props.navigation.state.params;

Comment: and then I'm trying to see the result using console.warn(item); and get the Item id, but I do not know how to manipulate it or to show data, I'm trying to using {item.title} but doesn't show the title of the movie.

Comment: is there another way to fetch data from API without using FlatList ?

Comment: what about using `for loops`?

Comment: ahhh I get it :)